Ignore Global Query Filter
I have this query that retrieves documents from a repo:
var kycDocs = await _kycDocRepo.GetAllAsync(a => a.CreatedBy == query.UserId &&
            (query.Profile.Role == UserRoleName.Customer ? (a.Status == KYCDocumentStatus.Approved) :
            a.Status != KYCDocumentStatus.UploadInProgress),
            ignoreFilters: query.Profile.Role != UserRoleName.Customer,
            select: a => new CustomerIdentityItemDTO
            {
                Id = a.Id,
                Type = a.Type,
                IdentityNumber = a.IdentityNumber,
                IssuedOn = a.IssuedOn,
                CreatedOn = a.CreatedOn,
                ExpireOn = a.ExpireOn,
                DocumentUrl = a.DocumentUrl,
                Status = a.Status,
                SubType = a.SubType,
                ExpiryStatus = CustomerHelpers.GetDocumentValidityStatus(a.Type, a.ExpireOn)
            });

This is the raw SQL query:
SET @__query_UserId_0 = 1214;

SELECT `k`.`Id`, `k`.`Type`, `k`.`IdentityNumber`, `k`.`IssuedOn`, `k`.`CreatedOn`, `k`.`ExpireOn`, `k`.`DocumentUrl`, `k`.`Status`, `k`.`SubType`
FROM `KYCDocument` AS `k`
WHERE NOT (`k`.`IsDeleted`) AND ((`k`.`CreatedBy` = @__query_UserId_0) AND (`k`.`Status` <> -1))

This global query filter is set on the AuditableEntity that the kycDocRepo inherits from
builder.HasQueryFilter(a => !a.IsDeleted);

I am to display all documents both deleted except the ones where the status are UploadInProgress to users that are not customers basically admins.
The major issue is that the ignoreFilters is not been executed.
Also I had tried some other approaches which only added another where clause where K is deleted.
What I want to do is to ignore the query filters and display the deleted documents.
I have tried this just to see if the query filter will be ignored
var kycDocs = await _kycDocRepo.GetAllAsync(a => a.CreatedBy == query.UserId &&
             (query.Profile.Role == UserRoleName.Customer ? (a.Status == KYCDocumentStatus.Approved) : true),
           
             ignoreFilters: ignoreQueryFilters,
             select: a => new CustomerIdentityItemDTO
             {
                 Id = a.Id,
                 Type = a.Type,
                 IdentityNumber = a.IdentityNumber,
                 IssuedOn = a.IssuedOn,
                 CreatedOn = a.CreatedOn,
                 ExpireOn = a.ExpireOn,
                 DocumentUrl = a.DocumentUrl,
                 Status = a.Status,
                 SubType = a.SubType,
                 ExpiryStatus = CustomerHelpers.GetDocumentValidityStatus(a.Type, a.ExpireOn)
             });

GetAllAsyncMethod
public async Task<IQueryable<T>> GetAllAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter, bool ignoreFilters = false, Expression<Func<T, object>> includeProperties = null, string includePropertiesAsString = null)
 {
     var entity = includeProperties != null ? LoadNavigationProperties(Entity, includeProperties) : LoadNavigationProperties(Entity, includePropertiesAsString);
     if (ignoreFilters)
     {
         entity.IgnoreQueryFilters();
     }

     return await Task.FromResult(entity.Where(filter).AsQueryable<T>());
 }


Show theGetAllAsync method, that's where everything happens.

my bad @GertArnold
thought i had added it

public async Task<IQueryable<T>> GetAllAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter, bool ignoreFilters = false, Expression<Func<T, object>> includeProperties = null, string includePropertiesAsString = null)
 {
     var entity = includeProperties != null ? LoadNavigationProperties(Entity, includeProperties) : LoadNavigationProperties(Entity, includePropertiesAsString);
     if (ignoreFilters)
     {
         entity.IgnoreQueryFilters();
     }

     return await Task.FromResult(entity.Where(filter).AsQueryable<T>());
 }

@GertArnold
here is the GetAllAsyncMethod

IgnoreQueryFilters() call does nothing if you don't use the returned IQueryable<T> (similar to almost all LINQ methods like Where, Select etc.).  In your case, entity.IgnoreQueryFilters(); must be entity = entity.IgnoreQueryFilters();

Also make sure that all methods called returning IQueryable<T> are passing pure EF IQueryable. Code like entity.Where(filter).AsQueryable<T>() is a bit of a red flag. If you have any code that results in generating an Enumerable/List of results, calling AsQueryable<T> will satisfy the interface requirement but ammendments to that IQueryable will no longer bubble down to the SQL since the EF expressions were already evaluated. (I.e. methods like LoadNavigationProperties) Your code is fine so long as "entity" is still an EF IQueryable. AsQueryable<T>() is not necessary.

As usual in this pandemic repository wrapping, we again see a method that doesn't add anything useful. Remove this redundant repository layer and query the DbSet repository directly, then you don't need all these complex parameters that mask what actually happens. It also makes it immediately obvious that the method didn't need to be async at all (of which this contrived Task.FromResult already was a telltale).

Thanks @IvanStoev
However, the GetAllAsync method is from a shared library that I can't modify.
I would have used raw queries but I have not seen the approach used anywhere in the project.
So would there be another approach to achieving the ignore Query filter?

Apply FromSqlRaw method to bypass the global query filters directly could be a workaround.

@FengzhiZhou that would have been a good work around but the approach but it had been used in the whole project.

I was able to fix the issue by applying this after the query filter
    if (query.Profile.Role != UserRoleName.Customer && kycDocs.Any(a => a.Status != KYCDocumentStatus.UploadInProgress))
 {
     kycDocs = kycDocs.IgnoreQueryFilters();
 }

